# not able to addsubview in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i have one homeview controller where i am adding one subview. that subview is subclass of uiview. but homeview controller not displaying subview.

here is my code.

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {

DetailView *viewDetailFinal;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailView *viewDetailFinal;


@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize viewDetailFinal;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    viewDetailFinal = [[DetailView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 588, 899)];
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self.view addSubview:viewDetailFinal];
}

#import "DetailView.h"

@interface DetailView : UIView{

}

-(void) loadView:(NSString *)str;


@implementation DetailView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    [self loadView:@"my test text"];
   }
   return self;
}

-(void) loadView:(NSString *)str {
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 25)];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [lbl setText:str];
}
```

Can any one suggest where i am wrong ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you presenting HomeViewController?

Comment: in my mainwindow.xib one navigation controller. and homeviewcontroller is default cotroller for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add label to your view like following ....

```
-(void) loadView:(NSString *)str {
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 25)];
[lbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[lbl setText:str];

[self addSubView:lbl];
}
```

Then in your view did load method of your Controller class ...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    viewDetailFinal  = [[DetailView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,460.0)];
    viewDetailFinal.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //Just for your verification
    [self.view addSubview:viewDetailFinal];
}
```

may this will help you

Comment: Hi abhishek. thanks for answering. yes it works for me. the problem is that my homeviewcontroller's initWithNibName method is not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation of the `-(void) loadView:(NSString *)str` method you are not adding the label to the view:

```
-(void) loadView:(NSString *)str {
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 25)];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [lbl setText:str];

    [self addSubView:lbl];
}
```

Comment: hi graver. thanks for answering. i have tried it but its not working.